# What's the difference between third-party surveys and follow-up questionnaires?

Tags: user-behavior, usability-testing, ux-field, ux-designer, testing

I know that if you want to use a follow-up questionnaire you need to use something like google forms, but I have seen in a video someone said if you want to use a third-party survyes use websites like ' ask nicely' and 'survey monkey' !! but these websites do the same thing google forms do?

thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be good if you mention your usecase too to minimize the discussion horizon.

Answer (score 1):

The main differences that I know of from my experience using both:

1. Some third party apps are able capture the results as soon as the user clicks on an option - and do not need to press 'submit' etc. i.e **even if they do not complete the survey** and drop off in between, you still won't miss out the semi filled surveys! This helps in increasing the number of responses. I really love this about a few third-party apps (not naming here so it doesn't look like I'm advertising)
2. Some of them have **more complex logic** than what google forms can provide.
3. They can have more modes of popping up - like a tiny bottom right panel (eg: like intercom of zendesk), full page, snackbar etc.
4. Advanced **analytics**.
5. **Templated surveys** that you can just duplicate and use.
6. Inbuilt options to define "when" to show up. Eg: Show up only after log in and **after 30 secs**. Eg2: Show up when user scrolls down the page 80%.
7. General better UX to the end user – as they are specialized in this.
8. Integration with other apps.
9. Support teams.

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of collecting sample responses from a population of people, questionnaires and surveys are effectively the same tool/technique.

A third party survey tool is basically a product that is not developed internally, so  in that sense Google Forms is no different to Survey Monkey if you are paying for this tool and using it to collect data. Most survey or questionnaire tools share a common set of features including the ability to create forms that collect different types of information, and reports on the responses of the participants.

A follow-up questionnaire is basically an additional step in the research process where you want to collect further information from particular participants that have already provided responses. So you can use a third party survey tool for your initial and follow-up questionnaires.

I hope that clarifies things for you.